# Power BI analyse tabel in Excel export

Tags: powerbi

I have a question about the function "Analyse in Excel" or "Analyse in Excel" in German when a PBI (Power BI) report has been published.

[image]

I read in a flat table in PBI and create some measures in PBI. Basically, it's about account numbers and the limits. A calculation is not necessary or possible here.

If I now want to analyse the data in Excel Pivot Table, I can only display the measures as values. An analysis of account numbers and limits is not possible, as limits are not measures.

What do I have to do to be able to select original data as values?

Thank you very much for your feedback and best regards
Andi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! I do not get it.

To make it clear - I stripped down a very easy example of my problem:

I'm loading a flat file with account, currency, date and balance information.
The respective Power BI looks like:

[image]

After publishing the report into the cloud I would analyse the data within Excel

[image]

However, when I try to bring the "balance" information as value in, I'm receiving the following message:

[image]

The balance is not a measure in Power BI. Any idea what I can do?

Thank you and best regards
Andi

Comment: You need to create a measure in Power BI Desktop which is `SUM(Example[balance])` then republish then refresh Excel then use that measure in Excel

Comment: Also, I know double click drillthrough works in Excel desktop. I’m can’t recall if it works in Excel online. It probably does.

Comment: Perfect GregGalloway! You made my day!
Double click in Excel Web does not working, however the measure is.
Thank you so much and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a measure from the table you are wanting to analyze and then double clicking on the measure value. This will pop open a new sheet and drillthrough to the rows detail behind that cell. It may give you the detail you are wanting.  I also believe it will give you proper data types on columns so you can do Excel analysis.

Comment: Thank you! However, I do not want to use only measure fields as values for the analysis in Excel. These values come directly from the original table and do not need to be calculated. I'm able to use masures as value but I'm looking for a way to uses non-measure fields as value. 
Thank you

Comment: @Andreas understood. The measure is just the place to double click in order to get additional columns and detail rows on the drillthrough sheet. Give it a try.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. If I use analyze within Excel Web, I can only use measures for the field type "Values".
You wrote "Try adding a measure from the table you are qnting to analyze.". How can I do it? The information do not need to be calculated at all. I need something like migrate to measure - but do nothing.
Thank you in advance